# Getting text to stay when changing scenes and then destroying when entering another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game designed for vision-impaired gamers. My score text currently shows up during the gameplay. Once you lose it loads a new scene (End screen), but I want the score to stay when the end scene is loaded and then have it reset to 0 when the game screen is loaded again, then removed if the player decides to go back to the main menu.

This is what loads the next scene.

```
public int amount;
public void ChangeScene(int changeTheScene)        

{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(changeTheScene);
}

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        amount += 1;
        Debug.Log(amount);
        if (amount == 10)      
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is how i track the score

```
void Start()
{
    count = 0;
    SetCountText();
    float x = Random.Range(325f, -600f);
    float y = Random.Range(250f, -450f);
    Debug.Log(x + "," + y);
    prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x,    y);
    loseObject.GetComponent<Lose>().amount = 0;
}

public void move()
{
    float x = Random.Range(325f, -600f);
    float y = Random.Range(250f, -450f);
    Debug.Log(prefab.transform.position.x + "," +       prefab.transform.position.y);
    prefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x,  y);
    loseObject.GetComponent<Lose>().amount = 0;
    count = count + 1;
    SetCountText();
}


void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: Please refer to: [Ask] and please show a [MCVE].

Comment: Hey, you have to make an object which hooks a score non destroy on load. Then it will persist over the scenes. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Hi, I only need it to go onto one scene and then disappear, what can i do for that? Also don't destory on load does not work on anything attached to the canvas, and i need a text object to continue onto the next scene not a game object. Any help? Cheers

Comment: use the dontdestroyonload function on the text, have some sort of pointer to that instance and then call destroy or pool the text when you want to get rid of the text.

Comment: Alox, would you mind writing me an example? Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to programming. (Designer xD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this would work, but to answer your question, I'm guessing this would do what you'd like.

```
using UnityEngine;

//This would be attached to said gameobject that displays the amount.
public class Amount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Amount instance = null;

    void Awake()
    {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = this;

            if (instance != this)
                Destroy(gameObject);

            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}

//Here would be what's needed to set the amount's parent.
public class SetThatAmountsParentToThisGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    void SetAmountParent()
    {
        Amount.instance.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
}

//And here you would destroy said gameobject that displays the amount.
public class DestroyThatAmount : MonoBehaviour
{
    void DestroyIt()
    {
        Destroy(Amount.instance.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Be advised that I haven't tested this and therefor am not sure if this will actually work. I'm writing it as an answer because you asked for an example and code is much cleaner and easier to read in answers.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help. I will give it a try ASAP and see how it goes. Even if it doesn't work i really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah it's still not working because im using a text to display the score and the whole canvas is getting destroyed.

Comment: right, then place the code of dontdestroyonload on the canvas gameobject and then destroy it. If there are other gameobjects on the canvas you would like to keep between scenes then have a variable keep track of the text and call the destroy function on the gameobject of the text.

Comment: OK! We're getting somewhere! It's keeping the score now! But 1 problem, it's not showing up in the game scene because it's taking the canvas from my other scene and staying on that, it needs to show up on the new scenes canvas. Any idea?

Comment: euh... then go back to what you had before, and use this function Amount.instance.transform.setParent(transform); inside the new canvas you want it to be in.

Comment: Transform does not contain a definition for setParent.

Comment: The name destroy does not exist in the current context

Comment: sorry, I forgot that destroy is from monobehaviour, and so does setParent, so be sure they extend monobehaviour, I'll edit my answer for what I know thus far.

Comment: Amount.instance.setParent(transform); This whole line is coming up with errors. Saying it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: right, lol, because I forgot to place it inside a function, my bad... I'm working on other things on the side for work, sorry for the somewhat pseudo code lol.

Comment: All good haha, did you want to make one last edit to it for other people xD. I see the question I posted everywhere but no straight answers.

Comment: "Amount does not contain a definition for setParent"

Comment: gah I should really pay more attention lol, I'm only writing it inside here and not in VS, Amount.instance.transform.setParent

Comment: "An object reference is required for the non static field" "The transform attached to this Gameobject null if there is none attatched"

Comment: And this is why im a Designer and not a programmer.

Comment: Ive been stuck on this for 2 days straight

Comment: it's SetParent and gameObject, sorry about that, hadn't capitalized the letters at the correct places. I almost always use autocomplete in VS to write code.

Comment: be advised that those classes would need to be attached to their respectful GameObjects.

Comment: All good man i fixed the gameobject one myself before, but the SetParent line is still the same as before.

Comment: here's an example of using SetParent, I don't have the error you're talking about so this'd be the best I can do https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

Comment: Oh wait it's just this error now. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Component.transform' Blinded.CSharp C:\Users\Phanteks\Desktop\Blinded\Assets\Scripts\Amount.cs 27 Active

Comment: My bad! I didn't have the latest revised script that you editied! All errors are gone now.

Comment: alright, it should work now then, just place those lines where ever you need them and make it work in the specific way you'd like it to. Best of luck and happy holidays, my workshift is almost over! :)

Comment: I cannot seriously thank you enough. You are a legend.

Comment: Merry Christmas aswell.

Comment: Sorry last comment, im just confused on what object i need to create to use this for.   public class SetThatAmountsParentToThisGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    void SetAmountParent()
    {
        Amount.instance.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
}

Comment: place the SetParent(transform); in the Awake() or Start() of the script attached to your other Canvas that's on the second scene.